# login button not responding or displaying anything

Tags: android, android-activity, authentication

I'm currently making an app for my thesis project and I used YouTube to watch several tutorials. Now, I followed a lot of videos and did what the narrator said, but when I run my project, my login button is not responding for some reason that I don't know. I added a picture of the event log. I hope it will help you guys to understand.

Here is my **loginRequest.java**:

```
package com.example.user.login_02;

import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class LoginReq extends StringRequest{

    private static final String LOGIN_REQ_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/login.php";
    private Map<String, String> params;

    public LoginReq(String pincode, Response.Listener<String> listener) {
        super(Method.POST, LOGIN_REQ_URL, listener, null);
        params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("pincode", pincode);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getParams() {
        return params;
    }

}
```

my mainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.user.login_02;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        final EditText etPincode = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPincode);
        final Button bLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);


        bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final String pincode = etPincode.getText().toString();
                final String username = etUsername.getText().toString();
                //final int id = etId.getInt().toString();

                Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            boolean success = jsonObject.getBoolean("success");

                            if (success) {
                                //String id = jsonObject.getString("id");

                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UserActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("username", username);

                                MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                                builder.setMessage("Login Failed")
                                        .setNegativeButton("Retry", null)
                                        .create()
                                        .show();
                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                };

                LoginReq loginReq = new LoginReq(pincode, responseListener);
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);
                queue.add(loginReq);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

my userActivity.java:

```
package com.example.user.login_02;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class UserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

        final EditText etUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String username = intent.getStringExtra("username");

        etUsername.setText(username);
    }
}
```

my xml for loginActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.login_02.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bLogin"
        android:layout_width="177dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:text="LOGIN"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/etPincode"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.13"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="59dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etPincode"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etUsername"
        android:layout_width="310dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="User Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.039"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPincode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etUsername"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etUsername"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etUsername"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/etUsername"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etUsername"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Pincode"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post the error log you received?

Comment: @Allaude Bluesky post the error log ...but i think you didn't send any credentials as param to server. for verification...you have to make volley request.

Comment: i upload a screenshot.

Comment: http://10.0.2.2/login.php check your url is reachable ?

Comment: i try to input my ip address, but still nothing happens when i click login button.